# JqueryのDataTables内で、ページ選択ボタンをtableに追加している箇所が知りたいです

Tags: javascript, jquery

JqueryのDataTables内で、ページ選択ボタンをtableに追加している箇所が知りたいのですが、
なかなか見当たりません。

分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

・使用しているJquery.datatables.jsのダウンロードリンク
[datatables](http://www.datatables.net/download/index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js#L14107-14177

ここら辺じゃないですかね？
.html( btnDisplay ) という行が14177行目にありますし。

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。
解決することが出来ました。